# BPost address validation C# REST call no success

Tags: c#, xml, rest, web-services, post

I am trying to validate addresses against BPost API from Visual Studio C#.
This is one of the first times that I work with Web Services.

I found sample code in PHP created by Spatie, and have it running on my computer in WAMP.
https://github.com/spatie/bpost-address-webservice
Now I want to have the same functionality from C#. I have not succeeded to convert it.

This seems to be the relevant part of the PHP code:

```
protected $client;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://webservices-pub.bpost.be/ws/ExternalMailingAddressProofingCSREST_v1/',
    ]);
}

public function validateAddresses(ValidateAddressesRequest $validateAddressesRequest): ValidateAddressesResponse
{
    $response = $this->client->request('POST', 'address/validateAddresses', [
        'json' => $validateAddressesRequest->getBody(),
    ]);

    return new ValidateAddressesResponse(
        json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true),
        $validateAddressesRequest->addresses()
    );
}

public function getBody(): array
{
    $addresses = array_map(function (Address $address, int $i) {
        return [
            '@id' => $i,
            'PostalAddress' => [
                'DeliveryPointLocation' => [
                    'StructuredDeliveryPointLocation' => [
                        'StreetName' => $address->streetName,
                        'StreetNumber' => $address->streetNumber,
                        'BoxNumber' => $address->boxNumber,
                    ],
                ],
                'PostalCodeMunicipality' => [
                    'StructuredPostalCodeMunicipality' => [
                        'PostalCode' => $address->postalCode,
                        'MunicipalityName' => $address->municipalityName,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'DeliveringCountryISOCode' => $address->country,
        ];
    }, $this->addresses, array_keys(array_values($this->addresses)));

    return [
        'ValidateAddressesRequest' => [
            'AddressToValidateList' => [
                'AddressToValidate' => $addresses,
            ],
            'ValidateAddressOptions' => $this->options,
        ],
    ];
}
```

This is what I tried so far in C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");

            var payload = "<@id>0</@id><PostalAddress><DeliveryPointLocation><StructuredDeliveryPointLocation><StreetName>Kaaistraat</StreetName><StreetNumber>1</StreetNumber><BoxNumber>1</BoxNumber>" + 
                "</StructuredDeliveryPointLocation></DeliveryPointLocation><PostalCodeMunicipality><StructuredPostalCodeMunicipality><PostalCode>8400</PostalCode>" +
                "<MunicipalityName>Oostende</MunicipalityName></StructuredPostalCodeMunicipality></PostalCodeMunicipality><DeliveringCountryISOCode>BE</DeliveringCountryISOCode>";

            HttpContent c = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

            var t = Task.Run(() => PostURI(c));
            t.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Feedback: " + t.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("End");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task<string> PostURI(HttpContent c)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://webservices-pub.bpost.be/ws/ExternalMailingAddressProofingCSREST_v1/");

            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync("address/validateAddresses", c);
            String response = result.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    response = result.StatusCode.ToString();
                }
            
            return response;
        }
```

Now I am getting a "False" as IsSuccessStatusCode.
What would be my best next step for troubleshooting towards solution?

Comment: Try adding at beginning of code : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;  Last year Microsoft pushed a security update that disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on servers, but did not change clients.  So if the default version of TLS on your client is 1.0 or 1.1 than code will not work.  Changing default to 1.2 may solve issue.

Comment: Thanks jdweng. I added the line and it runs, but it doesn't change the response of my web call.

Comment: We need to find out if TLS is passing or the issue is something else.  Best way of determining is using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  The TLS occurs before the HTTP Request.  So sniffer will show on successful request a TLS section and then a Requst.  If no request that TLS is failing.  Check version of TLS and the certificate block.  The certificate block is sent from server to client with a list of certificate names and encryption mode. TLS is failing in your case Encryption mode not supported by version of Net.  You should use Net 4.7.2 or later where TLS is done in operting system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to authenticate yourself to the service. If you send this request with Postman you get a 403 with an `Access Denied` body.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Kristoffer. It seems that the PHP version is not authenticating either, and it is working from the same computer. I will investigate further to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Postman indeed indicated error 403 when the input was not formatted correctly.
Introducing a var_dump(json_encode($validateAddressesRequest->getBody())) in the PHP code helped to find the correct syntax.

For future reference, this is the code that does work now, as generated from Postman.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Start");

        var client = new RestClient("https://webservices-pub.bpost.be/ws/ExternalMailingAddressProofingCSREST_v1/address/validateAddresses");
        String input = "{\"ValidateAddressesRequest\":{\"AddressToValidateList\":{\"AddressToValidate\":[{\"@id\":0,\"PostalAddress\":{\"DeliveryPointLocation\":{\"StructuredDeliveryPointLocation\":{\"StreetName\":\"Kaaistrat\",\"StreetNumber\":\"1\",\"BoxNumber\":\"\"}},\"PostalCodeMunicipality\":{\"StructuredPostalCodeMunicipality\":{\"PostalCode\":\"8400\",\"MunicipalityName\":\"Oostende\"}}},\"DeliveringCountryISOCode\":\"BELGIE\"},{\"@id\":1,\"PostalAddress\":{\"DeliveryPointLocation\":{\"StructuredDeliveryPointLocation\":{\"StreetName\":\"Leanderhof\",\"StreetNumber\":\"\",\"BoxNumber\":\"\"}},\"PostalCodeMunicipality\":{\"StructuredPostalCodeMunicipality\":{\"PostalCode\":\"8550\",\"MunicipalityName\":\"Zwevegem\"}}},\"DeliveringCountryISOCode\":\"BELGIE\"}]},\"ValidateAddressOptions\":[]}}";
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", "AWSALB=2BqLxFZuWQumzA1q6UhL1Pza0w8Lq3FGCUfB2+aqjOYulz1gvQUfXgRLps4I3FEhyb/TRyZaAPxCaHWZ8ISg2/Mq5BRCZX+5NqnVll7EwiOkdSB9sIf9EfcWzvJI; AWSALBCORS=2BqLxFZuWQumzA1q6UhL1Pza0w8Lq3FGCUfB2+aqjOYulz1gvQUfXgRLps4I3FEhyb/TRyZaAPxCaHWZ8ISg2/Mq5BRCZX+5NqnVll7EwiOkdSB9sIf9EfcWzvJI; webservices-pub.bpost.be=2936274954.64288.0000");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", input, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

        Console.Read();
```